# Is it true that $0<0$ is a part of the proof for a unique fixed point of a contraction map?

Tags: metric-spaces, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

I think it isn't, but my friend told me that this statement is true, he said that $0<0$ is even part of the proof for a unique fixed point of a contraction map.

I google it but I couldn't find anything.

Here is the proof according to him:

Take a contraction map $T$, so $d(Tx,Ty)≤qd(x,y)$ where $q\in[0,1)$. Now assume there are two fixed points, say $x_1,x_2$. Then we have: $$0\leq d(x_1,x_2)=d(Tx_1,Tx_2)\leq qd(x_1,x_2) ⇒0\leq(1−q)d(x_1,x_2)\leq0$$ But this can hold only if $d(x_1,x_2)=0$, which implies $x_1=x_2$. But that also gives us: 
$$d(x_1,x_2)<d(x_1,x_2)⇒ 0<0 $$

Comment: where are you getting "But that also gives us"? what the argument shows is that $x_1=x_2$, i.e. there is at most one fixed point, i.e. the fixed point, if it exists, is unique.

Comment: Your final statement is a "vacuous truth": you can prove anything from a false premise. Since $d(x_1, x_2) < d(x_1, x_2)$ is false, you can indeed use it to prove $0 < 0$.

Answer (score 4):

It is not true ("that $0<0$ is a part of the proof for a unique fixed point of a contraction map").  Your proof stops at "$x_1=x_2$."  Anything after that is probably gibberish that drops the equality part of $\leq$ for no good reason.  (I wouldn't know, I'm ignoring that wrong part at the end.)